# pytube: urllib.error.httperror: http error 404: not found

Tags: pytube

```
raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
```

urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found

please help what this error

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed by Ssuwani. You can install Pytube from

pip install git+https://github.com/ssuwani/pytube  .